# Z score stats question

Tags: self-study, z-score

Weight of people question:

Mean: 82kg, standard deviation 18kg.

75% of all people are at least how many kg?

Using the table, I get a z score of 0.67 or 0.68. So my answer is either 94.06 kg or 94.24 kg both of which were marked as incorrect. Am I doing something wrong, or thinking about it incorrectly?

0.68 = (x-82)/18 -> x=94.24

Comment: It's asking you for the weight that at least 75% of people are heavier than.

Answer (score 1):

The 25th percentile of the standard normal is $-0.6744898$

So, 75% of people will be no more than $0.6744898$ standard deviations below the mean. That is, they will be greater than

$$ 82 - 18 \times 0.6744898 = 69.85918 $$

Your thinking was on the right track but you looked up the 75th percentile instead of the 25th (i.e. the value where 75% are $\geq$).

Comment: @INeedHelp, no prob